# Dataframe has a column that is a list of dictionaries and I need to parse them into new coluimns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a column called actions with a list of dictionaries. The format is {source:int, action:string} and i need to parse it into new columns for each, but the number of records in each action cell is variable.

the data looks like this:

```
|Id  |action                                                     |
|1   |[{"E": 4, "action": "views"}, {"A": 58, "action": "views"}]|
|2   |[{"A": 74, "action": "clicks"}]                            |
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
|Id|Source|Value|Action|
|1 |E     |4    |views |
|1 |A     |58   |views |
|2 |A     |74   |clicks|
```

The number of dictionaries in the action column can be up to 10

I've tried a few solutions like this one [pandas DataFrame: normalize one JSON column and merge with other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671693/pandas-dataframe-normalize-one-json-column-and-merge-with-other-columns)

but it tells me that DataFrame was not called properly for the first solution and that str has no attribute  value for the second one. Even beyond that it's not quite the solution i need because i need to rename a column source and put the A/E/etc value in it.

Comment: Why do you have a df with dictionaries in it in the first place? Are you in control of that step? This problem is better-fixed upstream

Comment: I don't have control over it, the data was supplied as a csv with the columns like that.

Comment: I'd use the `csv` module and try re-jig the data with that before creating a dataframe tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rebuild your DataFrame data using list comprehension:

**UPDATE:** so the `action` column is a **string** field, not a Python data structure. You can pre-process it using **json.loads** which will be less error-prone in terms of parsing data structures from a string.

```
import json

# original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([
        (1, '[{"E": 4, "action": "views"}, {"A": 58, "action": "views"}]') 
      , (2, '[{"A": 74, "action": "clicks"}]') 
    ], 
    columns=['Id', 'action']
)

# new dataframe
df_new = pd.DataFrame(
    [ (id, k, v, i['action']) for id,act in zip(df.Id, df.action.apply(json.loads))
                              for i in act
                              for k,v in i.items() if k != 'action' 
    ],
    columns=['Id', 'Source', 'Value', 'Action']
)

print(new_df)
#   Id Source  Value  Action
#0   1      E      4   views
#1   1      A     58   views
#2   2      A     74  clicks
```

Comment: Im still getting the error str object has no attribute items which makes no sense because all of the data is in that format

Comment: @DBA108642, did not notice that action is a string field, you can parse it using `json.loads` before processing the Python data structure.

Comment: well it's technically an object type. i've tried doing a json.loads on the column but it throws the error that you can't pass a series to that function

Comment: @DBA108642, using `df.action.apply(json.loads)`, can you try my updated answer.

Comment: I literally love you so gd much

Answer (score 2):

I will using [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939)

```
yourdf=unnesting(df,['action']).reset_index(drop=True)
s=pd.DataFrame(yourdf.action.tolist()).reset_index().melt(['action','index']).dropna().set_index('index')

yourdf=pd.concat([yourdf,s],axis = 1)
yourdf
                          action  ID  action variable  value
0    {'E': 4, 'action': 'views'}   1   views        E    4.0
1   {'A': 58, 'action': 'views'}   1   views        A   58.0
2  {'A': 74, 'action': 'clicks'}   2  clicks        A   74.0
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Comment: This looks good, but im getting the following error: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Answer (score 1):

I did mine the long way but it should give you the output you desire. I just unnest the dictionaries inside the column of the dataframe. This only works if the dictionaries only take the format you show in the example dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2],
                   'action': [[{"E": 4, "action": "views"}, 
                               {"A": 58, "action": "views"}], 
                              [{"A": 74, "action": "clicks"}]]}
                 )

df_list = []
cols = ['id', 'source', 'value', 'action']
for x in df.index:
    for actions in df.loc[x, 'action']:
        row = []
        row.append(df.loc[x,'id'])
        for k,v in actions.items():
            if k == 'action':
                row.append(v)
            else:
                row.append(k)
                row.append(v)    
        df_list.append(row)
test = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=cols)
```

Which gives this output

```
   id source  value  action
0   1      E      4   views
1   1      A     58   views
2   2      A     74  clicks
```

Comment: This works with the sample data but when I apply it to my whole dataset i get the error "'str' has no attribute 'items'" on the line for k,v in actions.items():

Comment: It means there’s an action column roe that isn’t a list of dictionaries. The code assumes all the data will be in the format in the example

Comment: Right, but looking at my data everything is a list of dictionaries.